# MVVMCross WPF - How to load MaterialDesign DialogHost in root (MvxWindow)?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvmcross, material-design-in-xaml

I am trying to add a reusable dialog host to my test app.
But unfortunately, the app always throws a **'No loaded DialogHost instances.'** exception.

The code is very simple.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<views:MvxWindow
    ...
    >
    <materialDesign:DialogHost Identifier="RootDialog" />
</views:MvxWindow>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : MvxWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : MvxApplication
{
    protected override void RegisterSetup()
    {
        this.RegisterSetupType<MvxWpfSetup<Domain.App>>();
    }
}
```

**App.cs**

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        ...
        RegisterAppStart<DashboardViewModel>();
    }
}
```

**DashboardView.xaml**

```
<views:MvxWpfView
     ...
     >
     ...
     <Button Content="ShowDialog"
             Click="OnClick_ShowDialogAsync" /> 
     ...
</views:MvxWpfView>
```

**DashboardView.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class DashboardView : MvxWpfView
    {
        public HomeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void OnClick_ShowDialogAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var view = new SampleDialog
            {
                DataContext = new SampleDialogViewModel()
            };

             await DialogHost.Show(view, "RootDialog", ExtendedOpenedEventHandler, ExtendedClosingEventHandler);
        }

        ...
    }
```

But when I put this line:

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost Identifier="RootDialog" />
```

inside the **DashboardView.xaml** it works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Has the `RootDialog` been loaded?

Comment: @mm8 nope its not being loaded I suppose because there is no DialogHost in the live visual tree when the xaml markup is on the MainWindow.xaml.

Comment: It depends on how the window is being used...please provide a reproducible sample of your issue.

Comment: @mm8 I'm actually not sure how the window is being used. In fact, I have not changed anything inside MainWindow aside from adding the mvvmcross base class.
Perhaps pointing the app start to a different view model is the culprit? Please check edits .. thanks

Comment: @mm8 here please check the repo https://github.com/jf-dynamics/SampleWPF

Comment: does the problem still exist?